# Member function calling - can I access it without an object?

Tags: c++, templates

If I have something like

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void callMe()
    {
        cout << "called";
    }
};

template< void (MyClass::*callFunc)() > struct A 
{
   void A_call()
   {
       callFunc();
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct A <&MyClass::callMe> object;

   object.A_call();
}
```

This doesn't compile since it says "callFunc: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments".

Isn't a class member function a compile-time constant?

Comment: Huh?  Regardless of the template syntax, how do you intend to call a non-static member function without an object?

Comment: This makes no sense on multiple levels, but to answer your immediate question: functions are not first-class objects in C++, so it makes no sense to ask for a function to be a constant.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `callFunc` as a pointer to a member function. To dereference it (call the member function) you need to supply both the pointer itself *and* an object whose member you're going to call, something along this general line:

```
template <void (MYClass::*callFunc)() > class A { 
    MyClass &c;
public:
    A(MyClass &m) : c(m) {}
    void A_call() { c.*callFunc(); }
};

int main() { 
    MyClass m;

    A<&MyClass::callMe> object(m);

    object.A_call();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the method `callFunc()` outside of the class `MyClass` and it is not static, then you will need an instance of `MyClass` to call it.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass::callMe
```

is a non-static member function! You can't call it without an instance of MyClass! The instance is passed as first argument, therefor `MyClass::callMe` is actually:

```
void callMe(MyClass * this)
```

which obviously can't be called without an instance of MyClass...